# How to write shorthand notations in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

IS there any way to write following things in short hand ?

1. public var testvar = Dictionary<String,Any>
2. public var testone: Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]

It will be great help to know if i can write this in short hand

Comment: `public var testvar: [String:Any]` and `public var testvar = [String:Any]()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Apple's documentation, [Dictionary Type Shorthand Syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#:%7E:text=Dictionary%20and%20NSDictionary.-,Dictionary%20Type%20Shorthand%20Syntax,dictionary%20stores%20for%20those%20keys.)

```
public var testVar : [String: Any]    
public var testOne = [String: Any]()
```

You can't assign a data type to a variable. You can only specify a variable's data type with `:`

I hope this helps. =)

Answer (score 1):

The first one wouldn't compile as-is, without `()` appended to the end. The shortest you can get it is:

```
public var testVar = [String:Any]()
```

The second one, similarly, could be:

```
public var testOne: [String:Any] = [:]
```

or

```
public var testOne = [String:Any]()
```

Depending on how you're using the file/type that these are defined in, you *may* also be able to omit the `public`.